# Display value in html <select> from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the folllowing select that allows a user to choose a color.

```
<select id="colorChoice" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="colorToSet" ng-change="setColor(colorToSet)">
  <option class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="color in colors" value="{{color}}">{{color}}</option>
</select>
```

As it is, the dropdown item is blank and when opened, the color options are showed. The user choose a color and this color is displayed on the dropdown item.

But when the page refreshes, that value does not remain displayed into the dropdown item.

I am now saving that value into the sessionStorage and I want to show it when page is refreshed.

```
$scope.colors = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'blue'];

$scope.setColor = function(colorToSet) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("color", colorToSet);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page refresh, you just need to get the value back from [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and set it to your model `colorToSet` like:

```
$scope.colorToSet = sessionStorage.getItem("color") || '';
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
sessionStorage.getItem("colorToSet")
```

let color = sessionStorage.getItem("color") || '';

and set value to color